# How to get request referer path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need the path of the referrer. I don't want the domain name. For example, if the referrer is
`http://www.google.com/adsense` I want `/adsense`.

Answer (score 147):

`request.referer` returns a string, but you can use [Ruby's URI Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#M009387) to wrap it and then simply ask it for its path:

```
if URI(request.referer).path == '/adsense'
```

Comment: I'm using that URI(request.referer) line and keep getting a URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?) error. any idea what this could be?

Comment: Hard to say what it could be without more info. Try printing just the `request.referer` into the logs to see why Ruby might not like it. (PS: You may want to ask your question as a separate question, rather than as a comment on the answer to another question. :-) )

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148470/ignore-urirequest-referer-path-for-previous-url-when-visiting-directly-to-a-pa) to learn more about `URI::InvalidURIError`.

Comment: Oddly enough, the referrer can be an invalid URI even if it isn't blank. I dicovered this with a referrer containing  a '|', which raised URI::InvalidURIError

I am wrapping the URI.Parse in a begin/rescue/end block.

Answer (score 29):

You can access referer with

```
request.referer
```

Comment: But referrer gives full url. i need the path

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link, @Fivell. I've added an answer with the information from it to this thread itself so that future visitors aren't plagued with link-rot.