# Ignore URI(request.referer).path for previous URL when visiting directly to a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, controller, uri, before-filter

I'm trying to save the previous URL in a session, I currently have this code:

```
after_filter "save_my_previous_url", only: [:renderForm, :renderQuote]

def save_my_previous_url
  if URI(request.referer).path
    session[:my_previouse_url] = URI(request.referer).path
  else
    session[:my_previouse_url] = URI(request.referer).path
  end
end
```

It works when you go from a page, to the form, then to the thank you page, but if you go straight to a form directly instead of clicking a link, I get this error:

```
bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
```

So I need to some how ignore this when there isn't a previous url.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll share a little technique I always use with ruby/rails when dealing with null or empty objects/variables.

```
def save_my_previous_url
  if request.referer.present?
    session[:my_previouse_url] = URI( (request.referer || "") ).path
  else
    session[:my_previouse_url] = URI( (request.referer || "") ).path
  end
end
```

**Explanation:**
The technique here is to assume that in the worse case scenario, we return nil from the method call request.referer. So, whenever you are passing a null value into a function and know that the next method call will blow up, pass this snippet as the argument:

```
( @variable || "whatever_value_needed" )
    
#alternatively:
( method_call || "whatever_value_needed" )
```

In this case the "whatever_value_needed" should be an empty string.

This technique works because the request.referer method call first gets evaluated to nil, more specifically a boolean false. Then, due to the 'or' || operator, the second operand is evaluated, which in this case is "". The URI object instantiation then runs smoothly because it accepts an empty string as an argument, and all method calls on this new object will work(...not throw an exception).

Comment: URI(request.referer) will throw an error when the the referer is nil or invalid. 
See my answer below.

Comment: did you read my answer? using `begin` is complete overkill here. That isn't elegant at all.

Comment: @Mike.MKrallaProduction I found that referrer may contain an invalid URI (such as _http://x.com?utm_term=a|b_). This will throw an exception for the line  in your code `URI(request.referer || "").path`.  I would be happy to find an more elegant solution.

Comment: I just ran your example in my rails console with `x.com?utm_term=a|b` and I did not get an exception. `[4] pry(main)> URI('x.com?utm_term=a|b').path`
`=> "x.com"`. It does not throw an error, but the URI algorithm assumes that due to the fact that there is no protocol, that the path starts with `x.com`, as it should assume. Can you provide a failing example? I'll be sure to test.

Comment: @Mike.MKrallaProductions I ran  `URI("x.com?utm_term=a|b")` in the console and got:
`URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): x.com?utm_term=a|b
 from /Users/xx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:176:in 'split'
 from /Users/xx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:211:in 'parse'
 from /Users/xx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:747:in parse'
 from /Users/xx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:1232:in 'URI'`
Maybe this is different in another ruby version?

I'd welcome a better solution -- I'm addressing this today in my code.

Comment: Interesting, so your example does not throw an error when I execute it (like I said before) so I will assume it has to do with version differences. The only time I get that error is if I am truly using a malformed URI (ex: a space char). *But*, I'd like to point out the actual error the original post contained and my answer indeed solves correctly `bad argument (expected URI object or URI string).` Go ahead and pass  `nil` to `URI`, you'll get the error that he is getting, and my answer targets that specifically.

Comment: @Mike.MKrallaProductions  why do you check for nil with the || "", after you have already tested if present?

Comment: This is only an example to show how use negation to avoid explicit `begin`...`rescue` calls. If you look at the original post (as well as my example), both are illogical. The `if` `else` literally is exactly the same. I was able to interpret the question but the overall logic of the code wasn't coherent as it is. But again, the solution to the error/question itself could still be interpreted and solved. For example, I would've assigned a local var `referer = (request.referer || "")` to clean this up as well as refactor the `if` `else` to make sense, but that wasn't the goal. Good point though!

Comment: If you feel it still wasn't helpful or didn't solve the original problem, downvote is applicable. It did solve the original problem and error as well as help the original poster himself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you handle both nil referrer and referrer's who URLs can't parse (e.g. urls like *http://x.com?utm_term=a|b* -- "|" causes the parsing to fail, at least in some versions of rub).

This code (or something like it) works for me:

```
begin
    if request.referer.present? && URI.parse(request.referer).path
      session[:my_previouse_url] = URI(request.referer).path
    else 
      session[:my_previouse_url]=nil;
    end
rescue URI::Error => e
    session[:my_previouse_url]=nil;
end
```